# Should I use Bitmap or Drawable to store in ImageCache on Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, drawable

I implemented a ImageCache. But I'm curious about what type to store in it will cost less.

Now I use `BitmapFactory` to get the images from the internet, so I get a `Bitmap` first.
Should I convert to a `Drawable` to store in my ImageCache or just store the Bitmap is fine?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store the Bitmap.  That's what you're caching and I'm not sure what you'd gain by shoving it into a BitmapDrawable first.  It would definitely take more space as a Drawable since it contains the bitmap anyway.  You don't really lose anything either way as both are convertible back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on if you want to cache an image with different state like a selector (pressed, focused, etc).
The bitmap will not contain this information compare to caching the drawable.